# Comparison of solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equations with different initial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-optimization, convexity

Consider a Hamilton-Jacobi equation:
$$u_{t} + f(u_{x}) = 0 \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times [0,+\infty)$$
with two possible initial conditions $u(x,0) = g_{i}(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i=1,2$. The question is pretty much straightforward: if $g_{1} \le g_{2}$, do we have $u_{1} \le u_{2}$?

When $f$ is convex, I know the [answer is yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556800/comparison-of-solutions-of-hamilton-jacobi-equationfor-different-initial-value) and the proof is an easy consequence of the Hopf-Lax formula. However, I would like to know conditions for this to hold when $f$ is *not* convex. I am particularly interested in the case $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$.

I did a little research before coming here, but all references I know give special attention to Hamilton-Jacobi equations in which $f$ is convex and satisfy $\lim_{p\to\infty}f(p)/p \to +\infty$. The only source I found which differs from this setting is [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00176512/document), which states that the Hopf-Lax formula holds when *either* $f$ *or* the initial condition is convex, an information I found nowhere else. In this case, if both $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are convex and satisfy $g_{1} \le g_{2}$, its seems that the previous argument using the Hopf-Lax formula applies here and one would have $u_{1} \le u_{2}$ indeed.

Comment: You need viscosity solutions for this. See Theorem 6.6 here https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/viscosity_solutions.pdf

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the reference. Going to take a look. But do I need viscosity solutions even for the case $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$? After posting the question I realized I could make a change $u \to -u$ so to obtain a H-J equation with $f$ convex, in which case the Hopf-Lax formula hold. The solution is then given by a change of signs and the property holds. Still, it does not answer the question for more general $f$.

Comment: Maybe you don't absolutely need it in special cases, but this is exactly what viscosity solutions are designed for (the definition is essentially made so that the comparison principle holds).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general case

$u_t+H(x,t,u_x)=0$ in $\mathbb R^n\times [0,T],$

where $H(x,t,p)$ is uniformly continuous for bounded $p$. The desired result holds when we have

$|H(x,t,p)-H(y,t,p)|\leq m(|x-y|(1+|p|)),$

where $m$ is a modulus of continuity. This condition can be removed if we have already known either $u_1$ or $u_2$ is Lipschitz continuous in $x$. The proof is based on the maximum principle.

**Reference:** Guy Barles, An Introduction to the Theory of Viscosity Solutions for First-Order Hamilton–Jacobi Equations and Applications, Theorem 5.2. [Link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36433-4_2)